# Correct way to associate user with tags, and ways to properly add them?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, user-expectation, users, tags

Context: An environment where users have a suite of various products at their hands, containing information about hospital patients. The people using these tags tend to be physicians or technicians who associate themselves with focuses/sub-specialties, displayed as user tags.

These tags help when users want to share information with each other through a messaging interface, they can filter users by tags when looking for users to consult.

My biggest concern with the user and user tag information is how to properly display temporary tags (tags users will be associated with for a set period of time), and concrete tags with the user.

Also: is there a better way to prompt users to edit their tags/profile?

Feedback is greatly appreciated!

[image: Made on Balsamiq Mockups]

Comment: Can you provide more context? Who is the user, an admin managing profiles being added to the system? Or am I adding myself, and what is the point of a temporary tag? Please provide the problem first, not just the solution so far...

Comment: Agreed. There's not enough info here but there are way too many parameters to consider. Kindly provide information like, "are all users physicians and/or technicians?", "Who adds and verifies tags?", "Is this a discussion/forum like community?" and most important. "What do temporary tags represent?"